# Understanding Psychosomatic ailments

Tags: suffering

I am given to understand deep mental suffering can inflict physical ailments. (very understandable.)

Specifically harbouring certain kinds of negative mental constructs, for extended periods of time, leads to certain kinds of ailments.

Are there any such contexts in the Buddha's teachings that point out, categorise these?

Answer (score 2):

Some quotes to this effect:

> "Over the past I do not mourn nor for the future weep,—
>   I meet the present as it comes, and so my colour keep.
>
> Mourning about the hopeless past or some uncertain future need,—
>   This dries a young man's vigour up as when you cut a fresh green reed."
>
> -- Jat. 538 (Cowell, trans)

and

> “Again, when a fool is on his chair or on his bed or resting on the ground, then the evil actions that he did in the past—his bodily, verbal, and mental misconduct—cover him, overspread him, and envelop him. Just as the shadow of a great mountain peak in the evening covers, overspreads, and envelops the earth, so too, when a fool is on his chair or on his bed or resting on the ground, then the evil actions that he did in the past—his bodily, verbal, and mental misconduct—cover him, overspread him, and envelop him. Then the fool thinks: ‘I have not done what is good, I have not done what is wholesome, I have not made myself a shelter from anguish. I have done what is evil, I have done what is cruel, I have done what is wicked. When I pass away, I shall go to the destination of those who have not done what is good…who have done what is wicked.’ He sorrows, grieves, and laments, he weeps beating his breast and becomes distraught. This is the third kind of pain and grief that a fool feels here and now.
>
> -- MN 129 (Bodhi, trans)

Also, many Dhammapada verses to this effect, e.g.:

> 15. The evil-doer grieves here and hereafter; he grieves in both the worlds. He laments and is afflicted, recollecting his own impure deeds.
>
> (Buddharakkhita, trans)

I can't think of anywhere that specific mental afflictions are enumerated or categorized, though.